# How to draw such a network diagram on LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, draw

I am quite new to latex and I would like to know how to draw the following network diagram from a Markov Chain. Thank you.  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We are happy to help! Please provide the source code that you have tried. In the case you have no idea, please refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193695/167081) to get you started. Then, update your question in case you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Just for a starting point.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{ell/.style={ellipse,draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm,inner sep=0.25cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\node[ell] (e1)at (0,0) {\color{blue}$SOC1$};
\node[ell] (e2)at (5,2) {\color{blue}$SOC2$};
\node[ell] (e4)at (5,5) {\color{blue}$SOC4$};
\node[ell] (e3)at (-5,3) {\color{blue}$SOC3$};
\node[ell] (e5)at (-1,7) {\color{blue}$SOC5$};
\draw [->] (e4) to [out=-20,in=20]node[right]{\color{red}$p^{\phi} (0)$} (e2);
\draw [->] (e2) to [out=-20,in=-40,looseness=5]node[right]{\color{red}$p^{\phi} (1)$} (e2);
\draw [->] (e2) to [out=-90,in=-30]node[right=2mm]{\color{red}$p^{\phi} (0)$} (e1);
\draw [->] (e1) to [out=0,in=240]node[right=2mm]{\color{red}$p^{\phi} (1)$} (e2);
\draw [->] (e2) to [out=190,in=-30]node[below]{\color{red}$p^{\phi} (2)$} (e3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you recognize true art when you see it. thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, English is not my mother language.

Comment: I mean this is very good :) thank you !